# Помогите , пожалуйста, понять в чем ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот само задание:
В первой строке перечислены имена людей, которые умеют играть на скрипке
Во второй строчке имена людей, которые умеют говорить по-немецки.
Напишите программу, которая выведет людей, которые умеют и говорить по-немецки, и играть на скрипке.

Sample Input:

```
Trista Macmaster, Gigi Wall
Roselee Mayhan, Rosamond Boan, Malik Madore, Keena Kopf, Trista Macmaster, Cortez Mestas, Barbar Mease, Elease Knudson, Chas Nevius, Serafina Shemwell
```

Sample Output:

```
Trista Macmaster
```

Я написала программу и она выводит у меня такой же ответ как в sample output, но в итоге пишет что задание выполнено неверно.

```
a={"Trista Macmaster", "Gigi Wall"}

b={"Roselee Mayhan", "Rosamond Boan", "Malik Madore", "Keena Kopf", "Trista Macmaster", "Cortez Mestas", "Barbar Mease", "Elease Knudson", "Chas Nevius", "Serafina Shemwell"}

c = a.intersection(b)

print(' '.join(c))
```

Comment: Запустил. Получил требуемый ответ. Никто ничего про неверное выполнение не написал (да и кто бы его мог написать).  Так что - разве  что скрин ошибки в студию.

Comment: Может быть нужно считывать имена с помощью `input`? Наверняка программа должна работать с разными наборами данных. Ну и на формат вывода заодно обратите внимание: на входе есть запятые, возможно они нужны и на выходе

Comment: как и сказал extm и как я понял, судя по вашему вопросу, это задание на каком то ресурсе, и логично, что там тесты идут через ввод, который у вас явно не задан...

Answer (score 2):

Если в условии задания есть `Sample input` ,переменные скорее всего должны задаваться тестирующей системой через `input()`, а вот как именно, надо смотреть в этом самом `Sample input` и самом условии задачи. Насколько я понял в 2 захода через запятую с пробелом. Попробуйте так:

```
a = set(input().split(', '))
b = set(input().split(', '))

c = a & b
print(*c)
```

Comment: Спасибо, но он все равно пишет, что ответ неверный

Comment: @Екатерина может там вывод через запятую нужен, попробуйте в таком случае последнюю строку заменить на `print(*c, sep=', ')`, или каждое имя на новой строке, тогда `sep='\n'`